# opengrok Index database(s) not found

Tags: java, opengrok

I'm using OpenGrok and get an issue when I try to search on a project.
I get the error "Index database(s) not found..."

It's a bit weird, because there are other projects on this instance and they work perfectly. It's only with the last project in my list that I have this problem...

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this error, when there is a problem with indexing of given repository. opengrok creates a "dirty" file in such cases under index folder eg. /home/opengrok/data/index/

Please follow the below steps to solve such errors.

1. Identify the repository on which this error is being appeared eg.
   test
2. Login to opengrok server
3. cd /home/opengrok/data/index/
    eg. /home/opengrok/data/index/test
4. Move the contents to a temp location 
       eg. mkdir /tmp/test; mv /home/opengrok/data/index/test/*  /tmp/test
5. Start indexing again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found how to resolve it.
It was because the indexes where to big.
So I went in the OpenGrok directory and clear them.
Then I launched OpenGrok again and everything went fine.

Hope this can help someone else!